# enable Instamojo sand box with instamojo-nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, instamojo

I am using Instamojo in my application with node js.
How can I enable sandbox mode using [`instamojo-nodejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instamojo-nodejs) module.
In Instamojo docs they mentioned to replace `instamojo.com` with `test.instamojo.com`, but with this module only we are mentioning keys to connect Instamojo APIs.

```
var Insta = require('instamojo-nodejs');
Insta.setKeys(API_KEY, AUTH_KEY);
```

Here where I can mention the test account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding the following line:

```
Insta.isSandboxMode(true);
```

This feature is available in v0.0.4 of the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instamojo-nodejs). Make sure you have latest version installed!